# Is it possible to memory map a socket to virtual memory?

Tags: sockets, io, rust, virtual-memory

I am looking for something similar to memory mapping a file. It would make the virtual memory match the output of the socket byte-to-byte, and would block when no new bytes have been received. Is this possible?

I am looking specifically for a solution for Rust, but if anyone knows another language that has a feature like this, I might be able to interface with it.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not a programming language specified feature to support memory mapped socket. The following doc may help you. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt

Comment: https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/syro/thesis.html In case someone's interested, this guy solved OP's problem and also provided a patch for Kernel 2.0.36.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It doesn't make sense. A socket is not a random access device, and the length of the mapping is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a memory mapped file, you specify what file, and what range of data in the file is to be mapped. The area of the file that is mapped is fixed. If the memory mapped file grows (for whatever reason) the new data does not get mapped.

In many systems memory mapped files are implemented the same way as paging. Instead of mapping the virtual memory to a page file, it gets mapped to the file selected by the caller.

What you are asking for does not make sense because you are asking for variable length data to be used with a fixed length data construct.

Comment: What happens when the memory mapped file fills up?

Comment: It just is full? I don't see a problem. You just would have to remap to access more.

Comment: That assumes a contiguous range of pages is available when you need more.

Comment: It wouldn't any more than allocating the memory if it weren't a socket would.